# Property 'password' does not exist on type 'User[]'.ts(2339)

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a problem in Typescript Code:

> Property 'password' does not exist on type 'User[]'.ts(2339)
> I have to create a interface or something like that?

Thanks a lot

```
usersRouter.post("/", async (request:  Request, response: Response) => {
  const userRepository = getRepository(UserModel);
  const user = await userRepository.find();

  delete user.password; // <<<< Property 'password' does not exist on type 'User[]'.ts(2339)
  return response.json(user);
});
```

In the UserModel I have:

```
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from "typeorm";

@Entity("user")
class User  {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;
}

export default User;
```

Comment: `User[]` is an *array* of users. You seem to expect a single one. I'm not sure exactly what you need to do but maybe it's as easy as getting the first one from the returned result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Vlaz said, the `find` method of typeOrm will return you every items of your table.

You should use the method `findOne` to retrieve only one item, see below :

```
usersRouter.patch("/:id", async (request:  Request, response: Response) => {
  const { id: userId } = req.query; // Get userId from query path
  const userRepository = getRepository(UserModel);
  const user = await userRepository.findOne(userId); // Retrieve the user

  if (!user) {
    return response.status(404).send('User not found'); // Send error to client 
  }

  user.password = ""; // Set password to null may be better
  await user.save() // Save changement in database

  return response.json(user); // Return user with empty password
});
```

As you see, I made some modification on your function, I think this is the correct way to achieve your aim.